# reset the $q resolve state in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I have a service that runs an ajax query which upon success forwards that to a second function to parse the response into an object.  The function that is initially called returns a promise using the $q library before the promise is resolved, which happens in the second function that parses the response into an object, and passes that object as a parameter to the resolve method.  My controller which activates the service uses the .then method to log out the response for testing.  This all works great the first time, but consecutive times it returns the resolve from the intial call, before the resolve is called a second time.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my code

```
app.controller("login", ['$scope','XMLMC', function ($scope,api) {
    $scope.login = function() { 
    //This is bound to an ng-click directive in the current route template
        var params = {
            selfServiceInstance: "selfservice",
            customerId: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
    };
        var authenticated =     api.request("session","selfServiceLogon",params).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response); 
            //log the response once the promise is resolved or rejected
        });

    };
}]);


app.factory("XMLMC", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    function XMLMC($http, $q) {
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
        var def = $q.defer();
        var P = def.promise;
        var that= this;

        this.prepareForPost = function(pkg) {
            return JSON.stringify(pkg);
        };

        this.request = function(service, request, params, host, newsession) {

            if(request === "analystLogon") {
                newsession = true;
            }

            var call = {
                service: service,
                method: request,
                params: params
            };

            if(host) {
                call.host = host;
            } else {
                call.host = "localhost";
            }

            if(newsession) {
                call.newsession = "true";
            }

            var pkg = {
                contents: this.prepareForPost(call)
            };




            $http.post('php/XMLMC/api.php', jQuery.param(pkg)).success(function (response,status) {
                    that.consume(response, def); 
                    //consume the response, pass the deferred object to resolve later

                }).error(function (response,status) {
                    def.reject(response,status);
                });

            return P; //return the promise, not the resolved object


    };

    this.consume = function(response, defer) {
        console.log(response);
        //log the response that was received.  For some reason this log happens after the log in the controller on subsequent calls to this service, not the first call.
        var resp = response[0],
            digested = {},
            i;

        digested.status = resp["attrs"]["STATUS"];
        var params = resp["children"][0]["children"];
        for(i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var key = params[i]["name"];
            var val = params[i]["tagData"];
            digested[key] = val;
        }

        defer.resolve(digested);
        //resolve at this point, after the response has been consumed and parsed.
    };
}

    return new XMLMC($http, $q);
    //return new instance of this object for ease of use in controller
}]);
```

Comment: You should probably create a new promise using `$q.defer()` for each request.

Comment: This was the problem.  I moved the definition of P and def to this.request and it works like a charm.  Post your comment as an answer please

Comment: @richbai90 a promise is an abstraction over a _single_ operation, once it changes state it will _never_ change state again.

Answer (score 0):

try this schema, i removed the creation of the deferred object and returned the promise chain initited by $http.post, not sure if will work but it feels like it should since $http returns a promise.

```
app.factory("XMLMC", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
   function XMLMC($http, $q) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;   charset=UTF-8';

    this.prepareForPost = function(pkg) {
        return JSON.stringify(pkg);
    };

    this.request = function(service, request, params, host, newsession) {

        if(request === "analystLogon") {
            newsession = true;
        }

        var call = {
            service: service,
            method: request,
            params: params
        };

        if(host) {
            call.host = host;
        } else {
            call.host = "localhost";
        }

        if(newsession) {
            call.newsession = "true";
        }

        var pkg = {
            contents: this.prepareForPost(call)
        };




        return $http.post('php/XMLMC/api.php', jQuery.param(pkg))
       .then(that.consume)

};

consume = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var resp = response[0],
        digested = {},
        i;

    digested.status = resp["attrs"]["STATUS"];
    var params = resp["children"][0]["children"];
    for(i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var key = params[i]["name"];
        var val = params[i]["tagData"];
        digested[key] = val;
    }

    return $q.resolve(digested);
    //resolve at this point, after the response has been consumed and parsed.
};
```

}

```
return new XMLMC($http, $q);
//return new instance of this object for ease of use in controller
```

}]);